# Rotating cubes in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation, transformation, glm-math

I want to have a cube that rotates around the center. This is something i can do with this transformation:

```
model = glm::rotate(identity, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); //rotate around y-axis
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(8.0, 0.0, 0.0));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)); //self-rotation
```

Now I want a cube that will rotate around the first cube as it is rotating around y-axis.
Imagine that the first cube is the Earth and the second cube is the moon.
I tried this, but it didn't work.

```
test = glm::rotate(test, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
test = glm::translate(test, glm::vec3(3.0, 0.0, 0.0));
test = glm::translate(test, glm::vec3(8.0, 0.0, 0.0));
test = glm::rotate(test, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
test = glm::translate(test, glm::vec3(-8.0, 0.0, 0.0));
test = glm::rotate(test, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // self-rotation
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Here is a picture of the rotations:
[image: Sun - Earth - Moon Rotations]

Comment: Are you using the matrix somewhere (like setting uniforms etc)? You seem to only have included the matrix operations.

Comment: @Lasersköld Yes, I'm doing this with uniforms, but it doesn't give the result i want. Do you think these transformations are correct?

Comment: I have not tried to figure that out yet, i think its hard to know from your question what does not work. If I were you i would remove all transforms and add them one by one to see what the results is. Often the problem can be just doing the operations in the wrong order, so just reverse the order could fix the issue.

Comment: usual cause is wrong order of matrix operations, or doing operations on wrong type of matrix (direct/inverse vs normal/transposed vs multiplication order) ...without MCVE and or description of what notations you use we can only guess which of the 2^3 combinations you got ...

Comment: @Spektre I added and image. Hope it helps!

Comment: You misunderstood ... by notation I mean what your [matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) represent ... if they are direct or inverse or transposed ... if you multiply vector by matrix or matrix by vector... as that part of your code is missing and correct answer depends on it.

Comment: @Spektre
 `gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(inputPosition, 1.0);`
where `model` is the transformation matrix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comment suggest you have this order of operations:

```
mvp = m_projection*m_view*m_model
vertex' = mvp*vertex
```

meaning `m_view` is inverse matrix of view and `m_model` is direct matrix of actual mesh.

So you should set `m_projection` and `m_view` once and then just updating the `m_model`.

I do not use GLM (have my own libs for math) however IIRC they mimic old fixed pipeline matrix math. So when I do this (C++/VCL/OpenGL/GLSL ... I know the points should be VBO/VAO I just wanted test quickly):

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//    ang   ,ang speed,body r,orbit r
//    [deg] ,[deg/s]   [unit],[unit]
float                  rs=1.0;          // star
float a0=0.0,da0= 50.0,r0=0.5,R0= 7.0;  // planet
float a1=0.0,da1=200.0,r1=0.2,R1= 1.0;  // moon
float a2=0.0,da2=250.0,r2=0.2,R2= 1.5;  // moon
float a3=0.0,da3= 20.0,r3=0.5,R3=10.0;  // planet
float a4=0.0,da4=150.0,r4=0.2,R4= 1.0;  // moon
float a5=0.0,da5=180.0,r5=0.2,R5= 1.5;  // moon
float b =0.0,db =50.0;                  // common self rotation
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    GLint ix;
    GLfloat mp[16],mv[16],mm[16],m0[16];
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    float aspect=float(xs)/float(ys);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60.0/aspect,aspect,0.1,100.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX,mp);
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-25.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mv);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm);

    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//  glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    // GLSL sphere shader
    glUseProgram(prog_id);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"m_projection"); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mp);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"m_view");       glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mv);
    ix=glGetUniformLocation(prog_id,"m_model");

    // sun
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,rs); glEnd();
    // planet
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(a0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R0,0.0,0.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.0,0.7,1.0); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r0); glEnd();
    // moon
    glLoadMatrixf(m0);
    glRotatef(a1,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R1,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r1); glEnd();
    // moon
    glLoadMatrixf(m0);
    glRotatef(a2,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R2,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r2); glEnd();
    // planet
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(a3,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R3,0.0,0.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,m0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.0,0.7,1.0); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r3); glEnd();
    // moon
    glLoadMatrixf(m0);
    glRotatef(a4,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R4,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r4); glEnd();
    // moon
    glLoadMatrixf(m0);
    glRotatef(a5,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(R5,0.0,0.0);
    glRotatef(b,0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX,mm); glUniformMatrix4fv(ix,1,false,mm);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS); glColor3f(0.4,0.4,0.4); glVertex4f(0.0,0.0,0.0,r5); glEnd();

    glUseProgram(0);

    glFlush();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Timer1Timer(TObject *Sender)
    {
    // this is periodicaly called by timer
    gl_draw();
    float dt=0.001*float(Timer1->Interval); // timer period in seconds
    a0=fmod(a0+da0*dt,360.0);
    a1=fmod(a1+da1*dt,360.0);
    a3=fmod(a3+da3*dt,360.0);
    a4=fmod(a4+da4*dt,360.0);
    a5=fmod(a5+da5*dt,360.0);
    b =fmod(b +db *dt,360.0);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I got this output (using my sphere shader):

[image: preview]

The shader just takes point `x,y,z,r` as a sphere 3D center and radius, emit BBOX quad and render inscribed sphere with normal shading. It also uses color and your 3 matrices.

So if I see it right you should do something like this:

```
model = identity; 
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render star
model = identity; 
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a0), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R0, 0.0, 0.0));
model0= model;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render planet
model = model0;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a1), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R1, 0.0, 0.0));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render moon
model = model0;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a2), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R2, 0.0, 0.0));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render moon
model = identity; 
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a3), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R3, 0.0, 0.0));
model0= model;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render planet
model = model0;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a4), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R4, 0.0, 0.0));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render moon
model = model0;
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(a5), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(R5, 0.0, 0.0));
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(b), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0));
// render moon
```

If this is not working then your got some other mismatch between matrix order and used math or the GLM behaves differently than I expect. I used common angle for self-rotations so you just add indexes for your bodies ...

Also beware old GL rotations use `[deg]` so if GLM want `[rad]` you need to convert the angles and angular speed constants ...

If you want to have something more precise/related to real world or better visually see this:

- [Is it possible to make realistic n-body solar system simulation in matter of size and mass?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

object A rotating around B order: self rotation of A, translate to offset of A to B, rotate about B, translate by B position. Since B is the sun which I assume is in your world origin, and everything is on the xz plane (Cartesian not OpenGL coords), this becomes:

```
model = glm::rotate(identity, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)); //self-rotation
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(8.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // earth is 8 away from sun, where unrotated about sun is 8 units east
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); //rotate about sun
// no need for another translation since sun is at origin
```

Then for a object whose parent is the earth, you first resolve that relationship before you resolve the parent to world relationship:

```
model = glm::rotate(identity, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)); //self-rotation of moon
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(-4.0, 0.0, 0.0)); // moon is 4 away from Earth, where unrotated about Earth is 4 units west
model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(-100.0f * time), glm::vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)); //rotate about Earth
// translate to Earth origin, which is calculate from above code block
```

Disclaimer, I don't use glm-math, this is just the order of transformation geometrically, and I don't know if it translates directly to glm::x

Comment: these does not match OPs notations ... this suggest DirectX style matrices (transposed and Inversed) in order this to work for the OPs case (old OpenGL style matrices) you need to exactly reverse the order of all your transformations